# How To Setting Scaling Value Equal To Browser Scaling Value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In HTML, initial-scale doesn't work and the main problem is when I zoom in on some pages, it saves the zoom level and when I change the page to another page, the zoom level resets to 1.0 but after returning to the first page, the zoom level isn't equal to browser's zoom level even if I removed initial-scale factor, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If thats not it, try setting the zoom factor to around 1.2